# RecyclerView scrolls up and then down

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

I am using a RecyclerView with ListAdapter and DiffCall to implement a chat view. As more data gets added in the middle for threads or replies, or at the end for new messages the RecyclerView scrolls up and down. When a new message gets add I scroll to the bottom and that is working. But if someone replies to message from middle or up, the RecyclerView scrolls down.

I tried all `app:StackFromEnd`, `app:reverseLayout` and different `LinearLayoutManagers` I am unable to stop the RecyclerViews increase in height and push down the last message.

```
override fun onResume() {
    messageViewModel.preprocessMessageList().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        handleUpdateAndScroll(it)
    })
}



private fun handleUpdateAndScroll(messageListRows: List<MessagesListRow>) {
    messageAdapter.submitList(messageListRows)
    val messageRowListSize = messageListRows.size
    getMessageListLayoutManager().scrollToPositionWithOffset(messageRowListSize, 0)
}


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/oneView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/twoView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

We have a recyclerView inside this recyclerView to render list of replies, that is the only thing I can think of that is different. And we have ConstraintLayout items for this RecyclerView and some of the nested RecyclerView. Plus the messageList RecyclerView itself is in a ConstraintLayout

Anyone any clue?

Comment: This is difficult to investigate without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @RyanMentley is that code update helpful?